# How to write a booleans for gender and average it out

Tags: python, pandas

I am stuck so I have a pandas data-frame all set up but I am not sure why I keep getting a error message so here is what I am trying to do.

In the data-frame I have gender in 0 and 1 already and I have another column with donation in cash. I am trying make something that will separate out the men and women and then average their donations

```
     if Donorlist.genderdummy == 1:
        print(sum(Donorlist.AVGGIFT)/len(Donorlist.AVGGIFT))
```

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: Booleans spelling error on my account

Comment: Bob the problem is if you have a list or pd.Series, s, that has some males and some females, it is s == True would return part Trues and part Falses, hence it is ambiguous.

Comment: Okay so I would have to create a new column in the data frame I already have with just men and women and then perform analysis?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use integers instead of booleans so you can average them without ambiguity.

Comment: Sorry if I am misunderstanding but I already have them in 0 and 1 form so they are/should already be int() unless I made a mistake when importing and need to check which I will do now

Comment: Yup it is in int